# iOS Team ID changed, not sure why

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I'm updating an app I haven't updated in several years. I re-upped my profiles, and after using Application Loader to upload the binary, I got the warning:

> Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['{teamid1}.{app}'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['{teamid2}.{app}']. This will result in a loss of keychain access.

When I go into the [membership](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership) page, it lists `teamid2` as my only Team ID. All of my profiles list `teamid2` as well.

I'm not sure how to debug this. Where did `teamid1` go? It's possible during my flailing about the developer page, I made a mistake, but I'm not even sure what to look for.